# xsl:call-template does not work in XSL

Tags: xslt

I am trying to call the below template from my code . But I keep getting javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: ElemTemplateElement error: incrementValue.For a different template I still get javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: ElemTemplateElement error: templateName.Since the stylesheet is too long I am pasting the relevant code of the stylesheet. Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong  ??

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = '2.0'
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-datatypes"
     xmlns:mngi="www.medianewsgroup.com"
     exclude-result-prefixes="xs xdt mngi dirReader"
     xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
     xmlns:utildate="xalan://java.util.Date"
     xmlns:dirReader="xalan://com.mngi.eidos.util.DirectoryReader"
     extension-element-prefixes="date utildate dirReader">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml"
                indent="yes"
                encoding="utf-8"
                doctype-system="/SysConfig/Classify/Dtd/MNG/classify-story.dtd"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="EM-dtdExt"
         >/SysConfig/Rules/MNG/MNG.dtx</xsl:processing-instruction>
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="EM-templateName"
         >/SysConfig/BaseConfiguration/MNG/Templates/MNG_story.xml</xsl:processing-instruction>
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet"
         >type="text/css" href="/SysConfig/BaseConfiguration/MNG/Css/MNG-story-nonechannel.css"</xsl:processing-instruction>
        <!-- Added By Sachin -->
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="EM-dtdExt"
         >/SysConfig/Rules/MNG/MNG.dtx</xsl:processing-instruction>
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="EM-templateName"
         >/SysConfig/BaseConfiguration/MNG/Templates/MNG_story.xml</xsl:processing-instruction>
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet"
         >type="text/css" href="/SysConfig/BaseConfiguration/MNG/Css/MNG-story-nonechannel.css"</xsl:processing-instruction>
        <xsl:variable name="UPPERCASE" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ '" />
        <xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
        <xsl:variable name="HubName" select="translate(/Article/Hub/HubName, ' ', '')" />
        <xsl:variable name="lowerhubname" select="translate($HubName, $UPPERCASE, $lowercase)" />
        <xsl:variable name="SiteRoot" select="'C:/TwinCitiesArticles'" />
        <xsl:variable name="DatePath" select="translate(substring-before(/Article/PublishingDates/WebPublish_DTTM, 'T'), '-', '/')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="PhotoDir" select="'photos/'" />
        <xsl:variable name="PhotoPath" select="concat($SiteRoot, $DatePath, '/', $lowerhubname, $PhotoDir)" />
        <TodaysDate>
            <xsl:value-of select="utildate:new()"/>
        </TodaysDate>
        <imageDir>
            <xsl:value-of select="$PhotoPath"/>
        </imageDir>
        <xsl:variable name="totalPhotos" select="dirReader:totalPhotos($PhotoPath)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="photoList" select="dirReader:readDirectory($PhotoPath)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="pName" select="dirReader:photoName($totalPhotos,$PhotoPath)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="firstPhotoName" select="dirReader:firstPhoto($totalPhotos,$PhotoPath)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="currentIdx" select="dirReader:currentIndex($firstPhotoName,$PhotoPath)"/>
        <totalPhotos>
            <xsl:value-of select="$totalPhotos" />
        </totalPhotos>
        <xsl:template name="incrementValue">
            <xsl:param name="currentIdx"/>
            <xsl:if test="$currentIdx &lt; $totalPhotos">
                <xsl:value-of select="$currentIdx"/>
                <photoName>
                    <xsl:variable name="photoFromIndex"
                                  select="dirReader:photoNameWithIndex($currentIdx,$PhotoPath)"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($PhotoPath,'',$photoFromIndex)"/>
                </photoName>
                <xsl:call-template name="incrementValue">
                    <xsl:with-param name="currentIdx" select="$currentIdx + 1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:if test="$totalPhotos &gt; 0">
            <photoName>
                <!--xsl:value-of select="$currentIdx"/-->
                <xsl:variable name="photoFromIndex" select="dirReader:photoNameWithIndex($currentIdx,$PhotoPath)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($PhotoPath,'',$photoFromIndex)"/>
            </photoName>

                <xsl:call-template name="incrementValue">
                    <xsl:with-param name="currentIdx" select="$currentIdx"/>
                </xsl:call-template>

        </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Can you paste the whole stylesheet.

Comment: Since the XSL is too long ,I have pasted relevant part of my stylesheet by editing itin the above post. I am not importing any stylesheets which are external.There are 3 photos in my photos directory.I have declared a template which iterates through number of photos in that directory and I need my output like<photos>C:/photos/twincities/photo1.jpg<photos><photos>C:/photos/twincities/photo2.jpg<photos><photos>C:/photos/twincities/photo3.jpg<photos>

Comment: @Sachin Paradkar: `ElemTemplateElement error: incrementValue` because you have an `xsl:template` element inside the content template of another.

Comment: @Alejandro : Even if I remove the xsl:template call I get the same error . When I try to call incrementValue template .

Comment: @Sachin Paradkar you still get the error when you remove the call-template or the actual template, or are you moving outside the main template definition like I presented below?

Comment: @whatsthebeef - I am calling the template exactly the same way you have specified below !!.I have moved xsl:template name="incrementValue" outside xsl:template match="/" but now I get the below error . org.apache.xml.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Could not find variable with the name of totalPhotos

Comment: @whatsthebeef - It seems to be working for me now . I am passing the variables as params within xsl:call-template for incrementValue. But I declared a new template and it worked for me . Thanks a lot for helping me solve this!!! Cheers

Comment: no problem, If my response sorted out the problem set it as 'the answer' with the tick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xsl:if, xsl:value-of and xsl:variable all need to exist inside an xsl:template, xsl:variable or xsl:param, I am not sure whether they are not.

An xsl:template must be a child of xsl:stylesheet only.

You need to remove the template definitions from inside the first `<xsl:template match="/">`

Define the incrementValue template seperate and put the content of the other template inside the main `<xsl:template match="/">`

so you have something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = '2.0'
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-datatypes"
 xmlns:mngi="www.medianewsgroup.com"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xs xdt mngi dirReader"
 xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
 xmlns:utildate="xalan://java.util.Date"
 xmlns:dirReader="xalan://com.mngi.eidos.util.DirectoryReader"
 extension-element-prefixes="date utildate dirReader">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml"
            indent="yes"
            encoding="utf-8"
            doctype-system="/SysConfig/Classify/Dtd/MNG/classify-story.dtd"/>
    ...

<xsl:variable name="totalPhotos" select="dirReader:totalPhotos($PhotoPath)"/>

    ...

    <xsl:template match="/">

        ...

        <xsl:if test="$totalPhotos &gt; 0">
            <photoName>
            <!--xsl:value-of select="$currentIdx"/-->
                <xsl:variable name="photoFromIndex" select="dirReader:photoNameWithIndex($currentIdx,$PhotoPath)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($PhotoPath,'',$photoFromIndex)"/>
            </photoName>
            <xsl:call-template name="incrementValue">
                <xsl:with-param name="currentIdx" select="$currentIdx"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>    
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="incrementValue">
        <xsl:param name="currentIdx"/>
        <xsl:if test="$currentIdx &lt; $totalPhotos">
            <xsl:value-of select="$currentIdx"/>
            <photoName>
                <xsl:variable name="photoFromIndex" select="dirReader:photoNameWithIndex($currentIdx,$PhotoPath)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($PhotoPath,'',$photoFromIndex)"/>
            </photoName>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: Variables used in both templates will have to be declared globally as I have done with `<xsl:variable name="totalPhotos" select="dirReader:totalPhotos($PhotoPath)"/>` above so they are available to both templates because at the minute they are only scoped to the template they are in. or you can pass them as parameters as is done with `<xsl:with-param name="currentIdx" select="$currentIdx"/>`. If there are variables that only exist in the incrementValue template move out of the main template into that one.

WARNING: This is untested as I don't fully understand the problem due to lack of input so I am only sorting out the syntax.

Comment: I do not get a error when I declare a new template but I only get an error while calling them.

Comment: I don't know how you aren't getting an error perhaps to do with which instructions are called first but it won't be able to find incrementValue unless under xsl:stylesheet or imported from another stylesheet